# R conditional distance measurement

Tags: r, conditional-statements, distance

I am trying to determine distances in a dataset but only if they meet certain criteria. I have seen lots of examples on here determining distances between two points but not sure how to specify which points I want.

The dataset (titled event.df) looks like this:

```
        X      Y       Tag        Date
   34.355 -7.662    151401  2015-09-22       
   34.546 -7.016    151401  2015-09-22    
   34.425 -6.987    151401  2015-10-20             
   34.554 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.555 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.554 -7.804    151402  2015-10-22
```

And I want to say, IF the tag IDs are the same, AND the date is the same, calculate the distance from those points (could be more than 2).

Comment: The basic idea is to split your data by date and ID, then use one of the other solutions you've seen. `split_data = split(event.df, paste(event.df$Tag, event.df$Date))`, `result <-  lapply(split_data, <<distance_function>>)`

Comment: For more precise help, please edit your example a bit: It looks like only rows 1 and 3 of what you share have the same ID and date, so the result would be a single distance. If more than 2 in a set are possible, include a set of 2 and a set of 3 in your example. Please specify whether you want something other than Euclidean distance (like if X and Y are longitude and latitude). And please show how you might want the results to look, especially if there is a set of 3 or more. Is there an ID column so you can tell which points in the set a distance corresponds to? What about the singleton rows?

Comment: Yes for a set of 2 there should only be one distance. For 3 or more it could be distance from any of the points (1,2,3,etc) or all. Euclidean distance is fine. Singleton rows should be ignored if there is no repeat in dates. Ideally the output would go into a new column

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Could you please edit your example as I mentioned, so that the sample data has both a set of 2 and a set of 3?

Comment: "For 3 or more it could be distance from any of the points (1,2,3,etc) or all"... so, you don't care which? Do you want to be able to know which post-hoc? Just choosing a random other point in the set is okay?

Comment: I have changed the data so you can see the first 2 would be a set of 2, and the last 3 a set of 3. Preferably in a set of 3 or more it would calculate the greatest distance but a random point is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a lot easier to code adding a single column with the maximum distance than it would be getting all distances or a random distance.

Here's an approach using `dplyr` for the grouping:

```
library(dplyr)

# write a function to find the maximum distance for each point in a group
find_max_dist = function(x, y) {
  cbind(x, y) %>% dist %>% as.matrix %>% apply(1, max)
}

# use dplyr to run the function by group and put the result in a column
event.df %>%
  group_by(Tag, Date) %>%
  mutate(max_dist_within_group = find_max_dist(X, Y))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   Tag, Date [3]
#       X     Y    Tag Date       max_dist_within_group
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <chr>                      <dbl>
# 1  34.4 -7.66 151401 2015-09-22               0.674  
# 2  34.5 -7.02 151401 2015-09-22               0.674  
# 3  34.4 -6.99 151401 2015-10-20               0      
# 4  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22               0.001  
# 5  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22               0.00141
# 6  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22               0.00141
```

Zeros are put in for size-one groups, but you can replace  those with `NA`s if you prefer.

---

Using this data:

```
event.df = read.table(text = "     X      Y       Tag        Date
   34.355 -7.662    151401  2015-09-22       
   34.546 -7.016    151401  2015-09-22    
   34.425 -6.987    151401  2015-10-20             
   34.554 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.555 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.554 -7.804    151402  2015-10-22", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked!! I can't tell what units the output seems to be in though, since it's not km or metres

Comment: The units are whatever units your `X` and `Y` is. It's just Euclidean distance, liked you asked for. `sqrt((x[1] - x[2])^2 + (y[1] - y[2])^2)`

Comment: I have tried going back and changing the 'dist' function in the original find_max_distance to distHaversine to compute accurate metre distances, but get the error
Error in p[, 4] : subscript out of bounds
Col 4 is my X variable. There are no NAs and the rows are equal. Any suggestions?
Thanks for the help!